# One huge or multiple small models for text classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, text-classification

I am working on classification of large text database (millions of textes) labled to some thousands of categories / subcategories (very similar to the amazon product dataset).

My question is, if i could get a higher (in general) accuracy by the creation of multiple models e.g.

- One model to get the main category (one main-model)
- Separate models for each main category to get the final subcategory. (many category-models)

  compared to
- One huge model over all textes and all subcategories.

I am wondering if the vocabulary that is used in the textes of a main category and their subcategories is easier (and of smaller size) and more precise to learn for a model? But there will be an additional problem if the main-model predicts a wrong main-category - then the search for the right subcategory will have no chance to predict the right result.

Is there any research on this? 
Any rules of thumb?
Many thanks!

Comment: Each text belongs to exactly one category, so there is no recall / precision, correct? If a text is assigned correctly, it counts into accuracy, there are no false-positives / false-negatives.

Answer (score 0):

don't know about research, but can suggest that first use precision and recall matrix for the main model (with multiple modelling techniques) and if any model for all categories gives precision and recall values above the threshold lets say 99.5% then you gotta go with your idea. If you fail to achieve this don't worry just try another approach.It's about trying and observing. let me know for anything else. Thank you.

Comment: currently arrount 75-83%. problem is that some subcategories are "sparse", means they do not have many textes assigned to them while others do have "thousands" of textes, so a model will always have easier to "match" with one of theses categories.